# Does not send image in the embed message

Tags: javascript, image, bots, discord.js, avatar

So it is not sending the avatar as a image as it should do, but there is also no error, so i guess i have forgot something?

```
execute(message, args) {
            const Discord = require('discord.js');

            if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
                let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor('0x0099ff')
                            .setDescription(`Your avatar:`)
                            .setImage(message.author.avatarURL)
                            .addField(`Link:`, `${message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true })}`)
                message.channel.send(embed1);
            }
            else{
                const user = message.mentions.users.first()
                    let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('0x0099ff')
                        .setDescription(`${user.username}'s avatar:`)
                        .setImage(user.avatarURL)
                        .addField(`Link:`, `${user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true })}`)
                message.channel.send(embed2);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally want to use [User#displayAvatarURL](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) instead of User#avatarURL.

Edit: Apparently, these properties are now methods. Put () after `avatarURL` and `displayAvatarURL` to make them work.